# Solution verification - show that $a=b=c$ knowing an equality.

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, fractions

**Question**

Let the positive real numbers $a, b, c, x$ be such that the numbers $ax + b , b*x + c$ and $cx + a$ are directly proportional to the numbers $c, a$ and$ b$.  Show that $a = b = c$.

**My idea**

So we know that $\frac{ax+b}{c}=\frac{bx+c}{a}=\frac{cx+a}{b}=\frac{ax+bx+cx+a+b+c}{a+b+c}=\frac{(x+1)(a+b+c)}{a+b+c}=x+1$

$\frac{ax+b}{c}=x+1$

$ax+b=cx+c$

Observing that the equality is cyclice we can suppose WLOG that $a \leq b \leq c$

We let the case of equality and we focus on $a<b<c$

Using this we get that $ax<cx$ and $b<c$ so we get that $ax+b<cx+c$

Which means that we cant have the case $a<b<c$, which means that $a=b=c$

Hope one of you can tell me if my rationament ans proof are ok. Thank you!!!

Comment: Everything you have written is correct, but you're missing some cases (which can be handled exactly like the case you excluded). With $a\leqslant b\leqslant c$, there are four cases:

$$a=b=c$$ $$a<b<c$$ $$a<b=c$$ $$a=b<c$$ You can group the two middle cases or the second and fourth cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are in proportion let k be a real number such that
$$
ax+b-ck=0\\
bx+c-ak=0\\
cx+a-bk=0\\
$$

Adding these three and cancelling (a+b+c) we get k=x+1 (which in in your solution)

Now we get by assuming no two are equal
$$x=\frac{c-b}{a-c}=\frac{a-c}{b-a}=\frac{b-a}{c-b}\\ \ \\x^3=\frac{c-b}{a-c}\frac{a-c}{b-a}\frac{b-a}{c-b}=1\\ \ \\x=1$$

Now we get a,b,c and a,c,b are in A.P
$$
a+c=2b\\
a+b=2c\\
c-b=2b-2c\\
b=c$$

Similarly we get a=b=c which contradicts our initial assumption that none of them are pairwise equal which means they are infact all equal

Ps.Its a bit weird using contradiction but its better keeping $\frac{0}{0}$ as far away as possible

Comment: I dont really see why you would use inequalities for this tho

Comment: Thank you so much for your idea. But still, my idea is correct?

Comment: it is from what i see mostly correct but as @jwhite pointed out you cant only that $\gt$